# Rerunning a complex pipeline from failed activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a complex pipeline with multiple tasks running in parallel.
During the execution of such a pipeline, if it failed at some point, will I be able to rerun the pipeline from failed step (without choosing any particular node in pipeline)?
Or should I use the option rerun from a specific step option?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-run the [pipeline from the failed activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually#rerun-from-failed-activity). But this is only applicable for the Triggered pipeline runs and not for the debugged pipeline runs.

Go to the **Monitor -> Pipeline runs -> Triggered -> < your pipeline run > -> Rerun from failed pipeline**.

This will skip the activities prior to the failed activity and starts the re-run from the failed activity.

If you made any changed to the pipeline, then you need to publish the pipeline before re-running it because it takes only the latest published changes of the pipeline.

**Here is a sample demo on re-running pipeline from failed activity:**

I took an array variable `[1,2,0,4]`and given this to a For-Each activity which runs its iterations parallelly. Inside For-Each I have assigned the `@div(2,item())` expression to an integer variable. This generates the error for the item `0`.

[image]

Re-run the pipeline from the failed activity like below after publishing the pipeline changes. Here, I have changed the array to `[1,2,1,4]`.

[image]

Now, it will skip the activities before the failed activity and executes the failed activity. Even though it skips the previous activities, it will take the changes from the previous activity, and you can see the error got resolved from those.

[image]

This is also can be used when an activity times out or canceled.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What if there are parallel activities in the pipeline and there are more than one failure point in the pipeline. While restarting from the failed activity, does it restart from all the failure points in the pipeline?

Comment: I think it will restart from the first failure of the pipeline in the case of sequential. In case of parallel activities, I think it will restart every iteration. As you see in my case, it executed all iterations even though some executed without any error.